# php include() won't work?

Tags: php, mysql, include

I am having trouble getting my `include()` function to work in my code. Basically I have a the `$order` array that has the order that my pages will be shown in.

In this case: page numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6 as seen in the `$order` array.

If I just post 6 `include()` function's with the exact path, the pages are shown, however if I try to include them under this `for()` loop it doesn't work.

`$order` `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 )`

```
$fields = 6;
```

The weird part is if I make the array 4,5,6,1,2,3 it work's perfectly:

`$order Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 3 )`

**Only show's first 3 pages**

```
for($x = 0; $x < $fields; $x++)
{
      $page_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id='" . $order[$x] ."'");
      $pageInfo = mysql_fetch_array($page_info);
      $pageNum = $pageInfo['id'];
      if($pageNum <= 6)
      {
           $pagePath = "page" . $pageNum . ".php";
           include($pagePath);
      }
}
```

What is confusing is I know it is reading each `$pageInfo['id']` because this is the following output:

**Output:** 123456

```
for($x = 0; $x < $fields; $x++)
{
      $page_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id='" . $order[$x] ."'");
      $pageInfo = mysql_fetch_array($page_info);
      echo $pageInfo['id'];
}
```

**This works**

```
include("page1.php");
include("page2.php");
include("page3.php");
include("page4.php");
include("page5.php");
include("page6.php");
```

Comment: Maybe try this? `$pagePath = "page" . trim($pageNum) . ".php";`

Comment: Could you be more precise when you say "does not work" ?

Comment: Sorry @Matthew, updated. It only' shows first 3 pages

Comment: do you change any variables with the same name as a variable in your loop in any of the includes?

Comment: @bryan, including inside a loop is not a problem. echo $pagePath inside the loop, check that it is displaying the correct file.

Comment: @Matthew an echo of `$pagePath` show the correct path's

Comment: Turn on error reporting and use `require` instaed of `include`, it'll help you to debug.

Comment: Good suggestion of RCV, most probably there is an error.
Add the following at the beginning of your script:
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: Also, think about [auto load](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: @RustyFausak actually showed me the careless reason why it wasn't working. Thank you RCV, Matthew, and everyone else who were trying to help me!

Comment: You are welcome, try [autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: @RCV i'm sorry, I checked out the link but autoload is way over my head I don't understand it

Comment: [CHECK THIS FIRST](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: Also, read [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/), will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `$x` set to some number inside one of the includes. If it is only showing the first three, then perhaps in page3.php you have something like `$x = 7;`.

Comment: This solved it! You were absolutely right Rusty, thank you! Thank you to everyone else who tried to help! It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously have the numbers coming out that you're expecting to see (1-6), because you are printing them to the screen. You've tried a suggestion of using `trim` which didn't get you any further.

My presumption is that your `echo` used for debugging is places outside your `if` statement, and that your `if` statement isn't running every time you expect it to. Firstly, try putting your `echo` inside the `if` statement to make sure that your output is the same, then put `var_dump($pagePath);` into it as well to ensure that your variable is what you're expecting.

Another thing you could try, you could make sure the file exists:

```
echo (file_exists($pagePath)) ? 'Exists' : 'Does not exist...';
```

You could post us the code in your included files to check that you aren't overwriting variables like `$x` or `$pageNum` etc from your includes - variables are global between includes and will overwrite eachother.

Finally, I know you'll have a good explanation for this, but this looks pretty longwinded to me, in **this particular** application, you could just do this:

for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    include 'page' . $i . '.php';
}

> SIDE NOTES:

**mysql_*** functions are deprecated and you should be using either PDO or `mysqli`. Resources:
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

PHP's [include function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is a language control structure, not a function, so shouldn't be used with brackets: (for you downvoters, I'm **not saying it can't**, I'm saying it shouldn't)

```
// good:
include 'filename.php';
// bad:
include('filename.php');
```

Comment: Nah this doesn't matter

Comment: Tryed `include $pagePath;` but still only got first 3 pages

Comment: It is not a problem and it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: doesn't matter PHP handle a lot of things in many different ways :)

Answer (score 0):

1) I would not recommend fetching the DB on a loop but keeping your example:
You could try inside your loop something like

```
if($pageNum ){ //lets omit the <=6 for the test.
  $pagePath = "page" . $pageNum . ".php";
  echo "include($pagePath);";
}
```

and check the results, maybe you are getting something different to what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($order); $x++)
{
      $page_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id=" . $order[$x]);
      $pageInfo = mysql_fetch_array($page_info);
      foreach($pageInfo as $p_info)
      {
          $pageNum = $p_info['id'];
          break;
      }

  if($pageNum <= 6)
  {
       $pagePath = "page" . $pageNum . ".php";
       require_once($pagePath);//If it can't find the file then it will kill page and show corresponding error
  }
```

}